# Creating a SQL polygon query for SDA_Query() function to extract geometry from SSURGO database

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, rgdal

I am trying to query the USDA SSURGO soils database using a polygon bounding box. However, I am getting an error message when using the `mapunit_geom_by_ll_bbox()` function for the bounding box co-ordinates listed below and I am at a loss as to what to do, I am hoping someone might be able to assist.

The function works fine for numerous other sites queried by the same script I have produced but in this case seems to throw an error message "no features found" after downloading 59.3 MB data.

```
require(soilDB)
require(rgdal)
b<- c(-78.85225,  36.09854, -78.30758,  36.54143)
mapunits <- mapunit_geom_by_ll_bbox(b)
trying URL 'http://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMNAD83Geographic.wfs?Service=WFS&Version=1.0.0&Request=GetFeature&Typename=MapunitPoly&BBOX=-78.8522>474281323,36.0985383812962,-78.3075831406237,36.5414279914723'

Content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' length 200 bytes 
downloaded 59.3 MB

Error in rgdal::readOGR(dsn = tf.full, layer = file.layer, disambiguateFIDs = TRUE,  : no features found
```

In addition: Warning messages:

```
1: In download.file(url = u, destfile = tf.full, quiet = FALSE) : downloaded length 62158033 != reported length 200
2: In ogrFIDs(dsn = dsn, layer = layer) : no features found
```

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Many thanks,

Pete

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had cracked this problem by using an SDA_query, but I still get an error with some larger bounding boxes, for example:

```
require(soilDB)
require(rgdal)

b <- c(-82.57186, -82.11829 , 29.51710,  29.91280)  
p <- writeWKT(as(extent(b), 'SpatialPolygons'))  
q <- paste0("select G.MupolygonWktWgs84 as geom, mapunit.mukey, muname
FROM mapunit
CROSS APPLY SDA_Get_MupolygonWktWgs84_from_Mukey(mapunit.mukey) as G
WHERE mukey IN (SELECT DISTINCT mukey FROM SDA_Get_Mukey_from_intersection_with_WktWgs84('", p, "') )")  
res <- SDA_query(q)

Error: SDA returned an error:MaxRows
```

Anyone know why this is? Is there some upper limit to amount you can download with an SDA query?

At the moment this query downloads a very large area compared to the bounding box and assume this is something to do with multipart polygons, is there some way of downloading only the parts of multipart polygons a bbox intersects with?

Cheers,

Pete

p.s. I am new to this so apologies for the formatting